# open my app from home screen through voice commands

Tags: java, android

I am working on a app and i want to get that app launched from homescreen  through voice commands just like "ok google". i read some where that it is possible but you have to root phone first and then it may work. Is there any other method without root.

Comment: You can keep a background service running and add a listener to it and keep checking for a particular word on which you would like your app to be launch.

Comment: how the thing will happen i know but how to code for it, is what i want to know,  provide me any link or code..

Comment: "how to code for it" I can't teach you coding now. But there a few links on SO you may find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828599/launch-app-on-voice-command-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251677/launch-app-on-voice-command-android . On github to know how to run android speech recognition as a service go to this link https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/